# Passing a function as an argument to array.prototype.filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, parameter-passing

I'm searching an array of objects for certain object-properties & values using the filter function, like:

```
myArray.filter((e) => (e.name == "test"))
```

To be more flexible, I wrote a small function where I pass property/value as arguments:

```
function findSomething(_property, _value) {
  myArray.filter((e) => (e[_property] == _value))
}
```

The above example works fine for "normal" properties. BUT when I try to pass a function "getType()" of the object, it fails:

```
myArray.filter((e) => (e[getType] == "something")) //... getType is not defined
```

while

```
myArray.filter((e) => (e.getType() == "something"))
```

works perfectly fine...

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance
Christian

Comment: `getType()` is a function. When you read the value from the object, you'll get a function. You must call the function to get the result: `e['getType']()`

Comment: Are you expecting `_property` to be the name of a simple property or the name of a function defined on the object?

Comment: please add a comprehensible example (with data).

Comment: @ Paul: I'd like to pass both, simple properties and function properties... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a property which is a function, you could check the property value first and take either the return value of the function call or the value of the property for checking the value.

```
function filter(array, key, value) {
    return array.filter(o => (typeof o[key] === 'function' ? o[key]() : o[key]) === value);
}
```

Comment: Wow, what a nice expression. It works perfectly fine, though I'll need some time to digest it. Vielen Dank :)